# Why does a second @State variable crash my program in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct AddTaskView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: DailyScore.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)])
    var scores: FetchedResults<DailyScore>
    
    let types = ["Exercise", "German", "Cold Shower", "Fast Food"]
    
    @State var selectedTaskIndex = 0
    @State var newType = ""
    
    var body: some View {
```

I can't figure out why `@State var newType = ""` causes the program to crash. (and it is independent of usage, so that is irrelevant as far as I'm aware)

Comment: What does the crash log say the problem is? I don’t see why that var should crash, but I can see other possibilities, e.g., you didn’t set managedObjectContext in your environment, or Task.entity() or DailyScore.entity() fail to find their entity descriptions.

Comment: This is all it tells me. Not super helpful as far as I know. `RemoteHumanReadableError: Failed to update preview.

Error encountered when sending 'previewInstances' message to agent.`

Comment: @Ian can you include a [mre]? What you have here is pretty incomplete and doesn't include any preview code, which is obviously relevant to the crash.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dHfMi6sU

Comment: @Ian can you edit your question and include the code here, not on another site? Links expire.

Comment: Run the code in the simulator or on a device to get more specific error messages.

Comment: Try adding your managed object context to your preview explicitly:

`static var previews: some View {
AddTaskView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
}
`

Answer (score 2):

Update: It seems to have just been an Xcode bug.